# I Build apk of my android project. Apk also build successfully. but when i try to install apk in my phone its not installing and showing error.?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk, android-install-apk

This file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the default apps setting page android studio build Apk this file does not have an app associated with it for performing this action. please install an app or, if one is already installed, create an association in the default apps setting page.

Comment: Where is error?

Comment: Please clarify what problem you are facing and what is the error. you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please post error from LogCat

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your instant run is enable or not? If so then i had similar experience and i solved by disable instant run as follows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that the apk is build, check whether the file is having the apk extension (appname **.apk** ).
Better way is to let Android Studio install it for you instead of building apk and manually installing it:

> Enable **'USB debugging'** from you phones **'Developers Options'** .
>   Connect your Phone to your PC and Click on **'Run'** app option in Android Studio.
>   Select your device from the popup window.
>   If there is any already installed app, or any internal errors, Android Studio will take care of it.